# adding a column to dataframe's copy without changing the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, deep-copy

I have pandas data frame. I call a function add_column, sending a copy of data frame. Why does the original data frame gets changed (has the extra column added)?

```
new_df = add_column(ori_df.copy(),"nameofnewcol", col) 

def add_column(df, name_col, col):
    df[name_col] = pd.Series(np.asarray(col), index= df.index)
    return df
```

The problem is ori_df is having the extra columns as well.
As per the documentation deep copy is set true as default. Can someone say why this is happening?

Comment: Works fine in my system..! Just check again

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. If not, try assigning a dummy variable and passing that variable to the function

```
df_dummy=ori_df
new_df=add_column(df_dummy,"nameofnewcol",col)
```